# Animate an element in Javascript on mousemove

Tags: javascript, mousemove

I have two DIV's of different widths on top of each other. The top DIV `displayDIV` is wider than the bottom DIV `captureDIV`.

In the `displayDIV` I'm drawing a dot who's X position is proportionate to the mouse position within `captureDIV`.

As you move the mouse in `captureDIV` the dot moves proportionately in `DisplayDIV`.

It makes much more sense if you look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p56Lcdnw/24/)

My code is as follows...

```
let capture = document.getElementById('captureDIV');
let display = document.getElementById('displayDIV');
let circle = document.getElementById('circle');
capture.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

function handleMouseMove(event) {
  const captureRect = capture.getBoundingClientRect();
  const captureWidth = captureRect.right - captureRect.left;
  const relativeX = event.x - captureRect.left;
  let percent = (relativeX / captureWidth) * 100;
  let roundedPercent = parseFloat(Math.round(percent * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

  moveDotTo(roundedPercent);
}


function moveDotTo(percentage) {
  const displayRect = display.getBoundingClientRect();
  const displayWidth = displayRect.right - displayRect.left;
  const circleX = displayRect.left + displayWidth * (percentage / 100);
  const circleY = displayRect.top + (displayRect.height / 2);
  const style = `top:${circleY}px;left:${circleX}px;`;
  circle.setAttribute('style', style);
}
```

I also have a number of buttons that can set the position of the dot within `DisplayDIV` such as...

```
let move20 = document.getElementById('move20');
move20.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  moveDotTo(20);
});
```

Using Vanilla JS not CSS tricks, how can I create a function to animate (rather than move) the dot from its existing position to the new position.

```
function animateDotTo(percentage) {
  // clever code here
}
```

I need to be able to call the `animateDotTo(percentage)` function from either a button or from the `mousemove` event handler.

The dot should always animate to its new position regardless of how the move is triggered. For instance if the mouse is moved out of the left side of the `captureDIV` round the bottom and then into the right side of the `captureDIV` the dot should animate across the `DisplayDIV` not jump as it does now. Equally pressing one of the `move to x%` buttons should animate the dot from its current position to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are drawing a circle and moving it around, I would suggest drawing to a `<canvas>` element instead of moving a `<div>` by setting its `top` and `left` properties. Even using `transform: translate(x, y)` might be better.

In order to smoothly transition your dot from one location to another, using JavaScript, you will want:

- The dot's current position as `x` and `y` coordinates,
- The dot's target position as `x` and `y` coordinates, and
- The speed at which the dot moves as a scalar.

Updating the current position is done at every animation frame with [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). With these in hand, and a way of applying the resulting calculated position to the dot, you can use a method like this one: [How to move an object using X and Y coordinates in JavaScript](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75880/how-to-move-an-object-using-x-and-y-coordinates-in-javascript) to move your dot (the example moves a canvas, but if you know the `x` and `y`, then you can set them to `top` and `bottom`).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, with thanks to [Billy Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1406083/billy-brown) for pointing me in the right direction. Using `window.requestAnimationFrame` is the way to go.

```
var currentPercentage;
var startPercentage;
var targetPercentage;


function animateDotTo(percentage) {
    targetPercentage = percentage;
    startPercentage = currentPercentage;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

function step(timestamp) {
    var fps = 7;
    var maxStep = 30;
    var distStartToTarget = Math.abs(startPercentage - targetPercentage);
    var stepSize = Math.min(distStartToTarget / fps, maxStep);
    if (targetPercentage < startPercentage) {
        currentPercentage -= stepSize,0;
        if (currentPercentage > targetPercentage) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
    } else if (targetPercentage > startPercentage) {
        currentPercentage += stepSize,100;
        if (currentPercentage < targetPercentage) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
    if (currentPercentage > 100 ) { currentPercentage = 100; }
    if (currentPercentage < 0 ) { currentPercentage = 0; }
    moveDotTo(currentPercentage);
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p56Lcdnw/28/)

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick in css transition will fix this.

Of course. You don't want it to animate when you're actually moving the mouse. So what I did is that I separate the transition css property on another class and then remove that class on mouse move, re-attaching it when we click the move buttons.

CSS

```
#circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;

  transition: none;
}

#circle.animate{
    transition: 500ms ease;
}
```

JS

```
move20.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  moveDotTo(20); animateDotTo();
});

move60.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  moveDotTo(60);animateDotTo();
});

move80.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  moveDotTo(80);animateDotTo();
});

function moveDotTo(percentage) {
    circle.classList.remove("animate");

  const displayRect = display.getBoundingClientRect();
  const displayWidth = displayRect.right - displayRect.left;
  const circleX = displayRect.left + displayWidth * (percentage / 100);
  const circleY = displayRect.top + (displayRect.height / 2);
  const style = `top:${circleY}px;left:${circleX}px;`;
  circle.setAttribute('style', style);
}

function animateDotTo(percentage) {
    circle.classList.add("animate");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8pm2grjd/

If you want it to animate even if you're triggering the movement using mousemove, you can disregard the class approach and just slap the transition property on the css. But this will simulate the annoying mouse delay effect similar to input delay on video games due to V-Sync.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for my use case. The problem outlined above is actually an abstraction of the real one. It has to be a Vanilla JS function not CSS to move the dot. Have updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: @dwkns But why? Making a pure javascript animation of a simple transition is only introducing extra complexity. It's possible, but you have to hack and slash through it. You have to practically get the distance your element is going to jump to, then slice that into specific portions and then do a recursive loop, slowly incrementing the current position of your element until it hits the final threshold. Very hacky for something that can be solved by CSS with custom easing patterns.

Comment: The actual use case is moving a symbol along a polyline on a Google Map in response to mouse move on an separate elevation graph. This requires calling a Google Maps function: polyline.set(symbol, percentage). Hence I need a way of animating using JS not CSS.

Comment: @dwkns I see. Cheers. You can follow the flow I gave you, unfortunately I do not have time to make a quick code of that